Action of the fundamental group in a pullback

I am curious about which niceness properties of spaces are preserved under homotopy pullback, and there is one which as I am writing this question eludes me. Take a pullback diagram $X\to B\leftarrow Y$ such that the fundamental groups of each of these spaces acts trivially on the respective $\pi_n(-), \forall n>1$. 
Then, denoting by $P$ the homotopy pullback of this diagram, how can I understand the action of $\pi_1(P)$ on $\pi_n(P)$, in particular is it trivial? 
My go to method of understanding the action of the fundamental group is via the action of the deck transformation on the universal cover, but I don't think see how to understand the covering space of a homotopy pullback. 
Thank you very much for any and all help.

Are you sure you want to ask about ordinary pullbacks, not homotopy pullbacks? I don't think you can say much about the ordinary case: For instance, you can write any path-connected space as the pullback of simply-connected spaces, e.g. via the cospan $CX \to SX \leftarrow CX$ where $CX$ is the cone of $X$, $SX$ the unreduced suspension, and the maps are given by including into the upper and lower cones of $SX$, respectively. In particular the $\pi_1$-action on $P$ can be arbitrarily convoluted.

@BenSteffan Oh yeah you make a great point, let me change this right away!

I believe that the action of $\pi_1 P$ on $\pi_n P$ should be trivial, but I don't quite have a proof. All I can say for sure right now is that it's true when one of $X$ or $Y$ is contractible.

@BenSteffan, do you have a heuristic for your belief? For me this isn't even intuitively clear. Though I agree in the contractible case.

You can convert the problem into one about fibre sequences of the form $\Omega B \to P \to X \times Y$, and in fibre sequences fundamental groups act in all sorts of ways that are very nicely mutually compatible, see Proposition 1.5.4 in May & Ponto's "More Concise Algebraic Topology," plus it's true of every example I can think of :)

@BenSteffan Oh thanks for the references, I'll go check them out!
